# Vue component with input provided by a function vs reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I understand that reactivity is a big deal in VueJs. However, I tend to use OOP for my front end development, and therefore data is often provided by functions. This will be naturally non-reactive, which can be overcome by using this.$forceUpdate.

The question is - is this a fundamentally bad concept? Or is it just fine? Is there a better way? Probably watchers can be used, but I feel like that would make the code more complicated.

Example:

```
<template>
   <multiselect
      :value="myclass.getValue('param1)" />
      @input="val => valueUpdated(val)"
</template>
```

Then in methods:

```
valueUpdated(newVal)
{
    this.myClass.setValue(newVal);
    this.$forceUpdate();
}
```

Note, *myClass* has async data, so by the time of the first rendering, it is not filled with the data. *MyClass* comes into the component as a prop, and it is a TypeScript class.
this solution works fine, but is there a better (correct) way?

Comment: Is `myclass` in the data object of the example vue file, or its belong to another vue file

Comment: @JakeLam myClass comes from props, but it is a TypeScript class.

Answer (score 1):

Doing/forcing view to update manually is a fundamentally bad concept. The view should update at the moment your data changes - and it should update automatically. This is what **reactivity** gives you. This is like going from a car with manual gears and 49 shifts to a car with automatic shifting.

The whole idea is that you define **declaratively** the behavior of your view - how it depends on the data model. Building the view **imperatively** is more tedious and error-prone and certainly less elegant.

OOP may work well in non-visual libraries - but for UI composing components with props and events works better.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I feel that it is not the best way to do it, but I have a hard time coming up with a better solution. I don't want the components to be heavy. all of the business logic is outside in TS classes.

Comment: Well, if the business logic is fully decoupled from the UI then you can rely on functional programming - when you need your business rules to be applied then you simply call your transformation function which accepts the old data model as input and returns the new data model as output. If you want, you can then make a `diff` between the old and new data model and decide which parts of the UI should be updated accordingly.